# Why first tab font's size is different from another tabs?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Android Studio 3.1, Gradle 4.1, Java 1.8

Android 6.0

I change font size to **Huge**

In my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/tile_preview_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tile_preview_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tile_preview_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/tile_preview_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_min_height_container"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchViewContainer"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="TabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabLayoutTextAppearanceStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabLayoutTextAppearanceStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/tabTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

And here result:

[image: tabs]

As you can see the first tab (**Brands**) font has different size. Why?